# How to insert Image in iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I'm making my own rich text editor. So instead of inserting an image through URL, I'm doing through local files.

Iframe

```
 <iframe style="width:100%; height: 300px;" name="richTextField"></iframe>
```

My Question is How to insert an image in an iframe?

```
        function image()
{
$('#myModal').modal('show');

var file = document.getElementById("image").files;
$('#uploadImage').click(function(){

   loadImageFileAsURL();

});

}

 function loadImageFileAsURL()
   {
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("image").files;

if (filesSelected.length > 0)
{
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    if (fileToLoad.type.match("image.*"))
    {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
            var imageLoaded = document.createElement("img");
            imageLoaded.src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

             //How to insert Image??
             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `myFrame.src = imageLoaded.src;` ?

Comment: Yes, but no luck ;(

Comment: BTW richTextField.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imageLoaded.src); this solved me..